# Java JPA Repositories - findAll without loading eager field

Tags: java, jpa

Is there any way in which you can you use a JPA repository findAll method **without** Eagerly loading a Collection field already declared as an Eagerly loaded field?

Comment: You could use EntityGraphs https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs

Comment: The thing is that the Collection field is almost every time needed to be Eagerly loaded, that's why it was decided to be annotated as an Eagerly loaded collection from the beginning. However, there are some very few cases where the information from that collection is not needed, and my question would be what should I do to not load them in that case when using the ```findAll()``` method?

Comment: IMHO it's better to set the dependencies to LAZY and create a findAll method that uses the entygraph

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what I will do in the end...